# Can the Oberth effect cause space-time distortions?

Tags: oberth-maneuver, orbital, spacetime

I am making the sort of rhetorical parallel between Oberth effect that I conclude
applies even to light because light is actually solid of some sort photons or gravity well of Earth/Sun/galaxy, black holes effect. If I am making any
sense. Oberth effect may cause space-time distortions.

Comment: inside your answer (thank you) that the mass(es) might I am happy to find actually that you explained better my question or completed it

Answer (score 1):

> Can the Oberth effect cause space-time distortions?

No, but the mass(es) used for the maneuver might.

Note that the *velocity* of the spacecraft performing the maneuver might cause a slowing of it's time relative to an observer, but:

1. At anything less than extreme speeds (a significant percent of the speed of light) it would be almost immeasurable.
2. As far as I understand, time dilation due to a relative velocity is not, technically, part of a space-time distortion - which is due to gravitational effects.

Comment: does the light itself bends (suplimentary question) forgive me another question /is not everything made of oscilation on different sort of waves  so actualy mass (es) or light (photons) are made from the dimension called time.

Comment: N.B. The [Oberth effect/maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect) really only applies to entities that can ***accelerate*** when they reach the lowest point relative to the mass that is used for the maneuver. As such, it would **never** apply to light.

Comment: so Oberth effect belongs only to intended planned actions, it cannot hapen  but from planned not to inertial entities then, why if trajectory would be just to the ecuilibrium point just the right edge curve

Comment: *"Oberth effect belongs only to intended planned actions,"* Not necessarily. Let's say a comet is coming in close to a planet. At the exact moment it is at/near the lowest point of approach, 3 non critical lumps of uranium near it's core come together and cause a criticality event that turns some water into steam, cracking the body in two, perpendicular to the direction of travel. They are now moving apart at 2m/s because of the force of the steam. If they are of equal mass, the 'front' half speed will now be 1 m/s faster, so it will get the advantage of the Oberth effect.

Comment: any phenomenon would do that would hapen to the comet do we agree?

Comment: Most of the time I can barely understand what point you are trying to make, so I cannot unequivocally agree. As an aside, I feel the original question is answered, and comments are not meant for 'chat' - especially not when raising new questions. Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155831).